# xp_sysmail_activate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mail

There are multiple instance that whenever I am seeing `xp_sysmail_activate` running in SQL Server, DB performance is degrading.  Whenever I kill the process, the database can't recover and restarting SQL Service does not help either so I have no choice but to restart the server. In relation to this, I do have questions

- what exactly is this extended procedure doing that causes performance
  issue
- any logs or area in SQL Server that I can look at to better
  understand this issue and troubleshoot (either using SQL Server Management Studio or TSQL)
- any alternative to killing this process that will not require server restart?

Version Details:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> 
(Build 6003: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Are you seeing anything to indicate that this procedure is the *cause* of your performance problems, rather than a *victim* of the problem? That you still see problems after you kill the sessions calling this procedure would indicate they may just be victims, and not root cause.

Comment: As a starter troubleshooting step for older versions, make sure you try upgrading to the latest SP - in this case SP4.

Comment: I am not sure it could be a victim or the root cause.  One thing I know is whenever I SQL Server is slow, xp_sysmail_activate is always there which is hugging all the CPU resources and then I have no choice but to restart the server.  I am also thinking it maybe my SQL Server version is outdated which I is why I posted my version to see if anyone experience the same problem on that version related to mail service.